# Why do I get a foreign key not unique error on an identity column?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, identity-column

If I try to create two tables like this in PostgreSQL 14.3:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
  id INT4 GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483648 START -2147483648),
  foo TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bar (
  id INT4 GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483648 START -2147483648),
  foo_id INT4 NOT NULL REFERENCES foo(id)
);
```

I get this output:

```
$ psql test -f bug01.sql
CREATE TABLE
psql:bug01.sql:9: ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "foo"
```

I thought `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` would have satisfied the uniqueness constraint. What am I missing? And how do I resolve the issue?

---

UPDATE: Applying Bergi's answer and comments, I added a primary key constraint to each identity column and that solved the problem:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
  id INT4 PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483648 START -2147483648),
  foo TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bar (
  id INT4 PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483648 START -2147483648),
  foo_id INT4 NOT NULL REFERENCES foo(id)
);
```

```
$ psql test -f bug01.sql
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can replace `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` with `PRIMARY KEY` and Postgres will automatically create a `UNIQUE` constraint on that field or you can just add the following line after field `foo` on table `foo` that creates the constraint: `UNIQUE(id)`

Comment: Because an `IDENTITY` column by itself is not  a `UNIQUE` constraint. You will have to also add `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` to the column definition.

Comment: @JSpratt, that is possible, but you would not have an auto increment field which is what the OP is after.

Comment: True, he can keep that whole line and add `PRIMARY KEY` to the field definition or add the `UNIQUE` constraint to it if he needs that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no. [`GENERATED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) just means it's harder to overwrite (requiring special syntax) than a `DEFAULT` value, and `AS IDENTITY` is just a fancy way of defining an implicit sequence, similar to `SERIAL`.

You still can insert duplicates in your column, either by [resetting the sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altertable.html) or using `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`, you must declare the appropriate constraints to prevent this. Simply make your `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table.